# Python Django : No module named security

Tags: python, django, module, virtualenv

When I deploy my project on an Ubuntu Server, using a virtualenv, I got this error :

```
[17/Sep/2014 22:29:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/home/zat42/myproject/monarch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 64, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/home/zat42/myproject/monarch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 168, in __call__
self.load_middleware()
File "/home/zat42/myproject/monarch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 44, in load_middleware
mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
File "/home/zat42/myproject/monarch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
module = import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named security
```

I don't know why there is this error my configuration works fine with a fresh install... But when I copy my current project, I got Error 500. I tried to deploy "part after part" but I can't find what's wrong.

Tell me if you need more of my files because I don't really know where is the problem...

Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy the virtualenv folder from your local machine to the server? Try copying the project files without the virtualenv and make the virtaulenv anew on the server without copying from your machine.

Comment: I did as you said, first I copied my project (from git repo) and then I installed a new env (using "virtualenv env").

Comment: Run "pip freeze", check if the packages are all there.

Comment: pip freeze
Django==1.7
MySQL-python==1.2.5
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2

It seems to be ok

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I met the same problem. Finnaly, I found I’m using django 1.7.1 to run a 1.8dev generated project. When I switch back to 1.7.1, and remove ‘django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware’ in setting.py, it seems ok.

Comment: I got this issue while doing runserver without activating virtual environment (virtual environment had the django of version 1.9 and system had the django of version of 1.6)

Answer (score 12):

So, I found a solution :

```
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'
```

This line is in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, from settings.py.
When I delete this line I have no more problems with the security module but I guess this is not a good way to solve the problem ... I guess this line is in relation with the crsf token and things like that.

Any other idea to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same problem. It turned out that I was inadvertently using my machine's version  of django-admin.py to start my Django project, rather than the one installed within the virtualenv. I ended up having to `source bin/activate` again after installing django within the virtualenv, before running any of the django-admin commands.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when switching my project from another pc. As i didn't like very much the option given to remove the

> 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'

I just created a new project and a new app, change the settings by hand and copy the rest of the files, and it worked :)

I'm guessing it has something to do with the secretkey of the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you previously used a **virtualenv** for this project make sure that you activate it for the next time that you will use this project `source bin/activate` or check to see that you use the proper version of `django`.

If you want to **remove** some middlewares then you need to make sure of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

use this it worked for me

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happen in django version 1.7.x when you are trying to open project created using django version higher than 1.7.x

removing `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'` helps but it create another problem `'session error'` or something

to fix this:

```
pip uninstall django==1.7.x //your current version of django installed
pip install django==1.9.x //or version that is compatible with the project
```

Answer (score -2):

```
(myvenv) pip uninstall django==(version)
(myenv) pip install django==(version)
```

Just it.