# Getting Improperly Configured error while running Django server

Tags: python, django, configuration, middleware

I'm trying to configure Django and on running:
`python manage.py runserver`, it runs the server correctly but when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, it gives me the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
        self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
        return self.application(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
        self.load_middleware()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
        mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_by_path
        sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
        module = import_module(module_path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
        __import__(name)
    ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.middleware.security: "No module named security"
```

Don't know what the problem is but on looking on the internet, I found something about having issue with middleware ordering. So here's my middleware in my `settings.py` file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: have you activated environment where you installed required python packages ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901481/python-django-no-module-named-security ?

Comment: Probably caused by django version mismatch. What django version did you install? What django version was this project made in? A common mistake is just to `pip install django`, but that only fetches the latest version.

Comment: Try removing django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware from your middleware classes

Comment: @Jileshl That doesn't really solve the problem. There is nothing wrong with that middleware entry.

Comment: I feel its an issue with django version mismatch or Classpath issue, however Can you post if the following file exists ?   <pythonpath>/site-packages/django/middleware/security.py

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? The security middleware was added in version 1.8.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using 1.6

Comment: Well, firstly, why? And secondly, why are you using instructions for 1.8+?

Comment: Upgraded to 1.8 and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you need to upgrade to Django 1.8, when security middleware was added.

Comment: I just copied the answer from the comments, so this question wouldn't appear in the unanswered list.